# How do I switch to JS mode in mysql-shell when \js is an unknown command?

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, shell, ubuntu

I installed mysql shell on my Ubuntu VM.

As per all internet sources, when I input

> mysqlsh

The default mode should be JS mode. However, my default mode somehow is python, and if I switch it to javascript mode by using

> /js

It doesn't even recognize that command. Mysql mode works fine though. I've tried installing and reinstalling a couple of times to no avail.

What am I missing?

[Here's what popped up when i switch to js mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBRHP.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your version of MySQL Shell was compiled without Javascipt mode support. You can download official version of MySQL Shell from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/

Comment: Thank you so much. This has stumped me for a week now. For some reason using the mysql-shell from snap does not have the js mode. Appreciate your help.

Comment: it still doesn't